# How to fix unsatisfied dependencies for injecting Models (javax.mvc.Models)?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, wildfly, cdi

I get this error while following this [tutorial for mvc 1.0](https://www.kodnito.com/posts/getting-started-with-mvc-1-0-jsr-371/).

> [ERROR] Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Models with qualifiers @Default at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject ch.xxx.controller.UserController.models at ch.xxx.controller.UserController.models(UserController.java:0)

I tried...

- putting my beans.xml into multiple places (resources/META-INF/beans.xml | webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml)
- changing the bean-discovery-mode to "all"
- annotated my User.class with @Named and/or @SessionScoped (not in tutorial)

This is my User.class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Here my UserForm.class

```java
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;

public class UserForm {

    @FormParam("id")
    private String id;

    @FormParam("email")
    private String email;

    @FormParam("password")
    private String password;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

and at last my UserController.class, where the error actually happens:

```java
@Controller
@Stateless
@Path("/user")
public class UserController {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Inject
    Models models;

    @GET
    @View("user/all-users.html")
    public void getAllREST(){
        List<User> allUsers = entityManager.createNamedQuery("User.findAll", User.class).getResultList();
        models.put("users", allUsers);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/create")
    public String getCreateRESTForm(){
        return "user/create-user.html";
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/create")
    public String create(@BeanParam UserForm userForm){
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(userForm.getEmail());
        user.setPassword(user.getPassword());

        entityManager.persist(user);

        return "redirect:/user";
    }
}
```

I'm really lost here, since I have no idea what more to change and what the actual problem is for such a simple form. And don't mind the plain text password, it's just for testing.

Comment: The error means that nobody is providing a bean of type `Models`. According to [javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/javax.mvc/javax.mvc-api/1.0-pfd), implementations of `Models` need to be injectable. Hence it falls to the implementations to give you that bean. Have you followed some guide that told you how to link the impl to WFLY? (I suppose you run wfly by the tags on the question). Quick googling gave me [this](https://www.mvc-spec.org/krazo/docs/install-javaee.html) which indicated you need some extra steps to get the impl/integration in.Note that I haven't tried it,just tossing ideas around

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with JEE MVC yet but this seems to be CDI related issue and should not be located in the MVC framework, because it should only make use of CDI.

The reason for this exception, as already answered, is because the CDI Container does not find any injectible implementations of this interface, and therefore cannot inject it.

Take a look at the javadoc which says, that any implementation of this interface needs to be injectible and request scoped. Are you sure that the implementing bean you expect fulfills these requirements?

https://github.com/javaee/mvc-spec/blob/master/api/src/main/java/javax/mvc/Models.java

1. Is there a beans.xml present in the artifact the bean resides?

   src/main/reosurces/META-INF/beans.xml (for JAR)

   src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml     (for WAR)
2. Is the implementing bean annotated with @RequestScoped?
3. If referenced via EL, is the bean annotated with @Named?

Another thing is, do not make JPA entities CDI-Beans and make them injectible, this is a bad approach and the Models interfaces and its implementations should not require it.